# Using returned JSON encoded AJAX PHP response within HTML <div> as values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have looked far and wide through many similar questions but none seem to do it for me. They're either unrelated or incredibly overcomplicated - and I'm new to javascript.

What I have is an AJAX form which takes some input, posts it to form.php where it is JSON_encoded and echo'd back to the AJAX call as a response.

```
<?php
... calculations
..
.
echo json_encode(array("monthly_saved" => $monthly_saved, "peak" => $peak)); 
?>
```

This is successfully handled;

POST form.php
200 OK
 41ms
HeadersPostResponseHTML

```
6018066.666666666667200{"monthly_saved":6.6666666666667,"peak":"10"}
```

Though now I need to harness these values and use them inside a HTML  as content!

> HELP!

My AJAX function:

```
$(function () {
        $('#quote_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form.php",
            data: $('#quote_form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                *WHAT I NEED TO FIGURE OUT*
            }
          });
        });
});
```

I have been trying to find a solution for hours, yet can't seem to figure this out!

I was thinking of putting something within the success function along the lines of a hybrid between:

> document.getElementById("graph_var_1").innerHTML = "(data.monthly_saved";

and

> $("#graph_var_1").html(data.monthly_saved);

What would work?

The HTML I need to populate with these variables is:

```
<div class="result_field"><div id="graph_var_1"></div> (saved <div id="graph_var_2"></div>%)</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly this:

```
6018066.666666666667200{"monthly_saved":6.6666666666667,"peak":"10"}
```

is not valid JSON, you must be echoing the number `6018066.666666666667200` previously, you should remove this.

Now the response will come in the `success` callback as `data`. If you want to access a specific bit of your response you can do this:

```
alert(data.monthly_saved);
```

This should alert `6018066.666666666667200`

You should be able to use `$("#graph_var_1").html(data.monthly_saved);` as you have already done to populate the DOM elements

Comment: Hi Jonathon! Thank you for your response, I'm on my way home at the moment but will attempt to sort it out when I get home - Thanks for the explanation! I think that should do it, but will send you a message if I get lost. :)